# How are a java Runnable object's other methods called?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am given some skeletons of classes that I must implement (I personally don't really agree with the design of the program but I am not at mercy to change it :( ) and they work in this manner:

I have a `Game` class which implements `Runnable` and represents a chess game.

A `Server` class will have a list of multiple `Game` classes that it keeps track of.

Ok this makes sense, `Game` implements Runnable so the `Server` can put each game in its own thread.

I am a bit confused at how java's threads work.

What I know is the following:

After tying my `Runnable` class to a thread and calling the `.start()` method, the `Runnable` class's `run()` method is called.

However, I have some other methods inside my `Game` class such as:

```
capturePiece()

playerMakesMove()
```

etc

In the current design, it is up to the `Server` to handle game actions. When a player wants to capture a piece, the `Server` will call `game.capturePiece()`.

In this case, is `capturePiece()` being run on the `Game` thread, or the `Server`'s thread? (the caller's thread or the callee's thread)

In this case, what would `run()` even do?

Comment: I am surprised how you even got and up vote on that question. This question is not clear/detailed enough for anyone to answer. If you want to know how `run()` works, you should read documentation, not post a question.

Comment: If you read through my question, I am asking "which thread are a `Runnable`'s other methods being called". I even said in my question that I understood what run() did, I was just curious how it interacted with the other methods...

Comment: @ringbearer: it's a valid question with adequate information and good discussion.

Comment: @Hovercraft the question is not clear because Razor is not clear on Threading concepts. Unfortunately, it seems, you also have not quite grasped the issue. I hope Razor comes back to read my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any method, in any programming language, executes in the *same* thread as the caller. When you call `Thread.start()` it runs in the same thread that called it.

Now, you know that the `run()` method of a Thread does not execute in the same thread as `start`. But that is because **start does not itself call run**. You will have to read up more on threads to get the complete picture but just imagine that start only crates a new thread with some data structure (the `Runnable`) and the newly created thread looks at that data structure, identifies the Runnable and executes its `run` method.

And that is really the *only* way control passes from one thread to another: one thread generates some data and other thread picks it up and processes it. Control does *not* pass from one thread to another, it is inter-thread communication and co-ordination.

If the methods of `Game` are called by `Server` then the threads are not going to have anything to do, are they? But instead, if the Server does not call the method directly but instead represents the action as data then `Game.run()` can pick the action and perform it, *in its own thread*.

Now the only question is where can `Server` put the data such that each `Game.run()`, running in its own thread knows to pick it up from. One option is to use [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The Server can put these `Action` objects in the queue and the Game thread can pick it up. How will the two know to use the same queue? There many different ways, one is for server to create the game with a queue and store a map on its side. As in the skeleton below:

```
class Server {
    Map<Game, BlockingQueue> games = ....;

    void createGame() {
        BlockingQueue queue = ....;
        Game game = new Game(queue);
        games.put(game, queue);
    }

    void foo() {
       Game game = ....; 
       Action action = ....; // identify the Game
       map.get(g).add(action);
    }
}

class Game {
    BlockingQueue _queue;

    Game(BlockingQueue queue) { 
         _queue = queue; 
    }

    void run() {
        while (true) {
            Action nextAction = _queue.take();
            // perform the action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by I don't agree with the design I am given. My initial thoughts were to put all actions in a queue that the threads' run() methods can pick up. However, the Server class already has direct method calls filled in...

Comment: @Razor that makes sense actually...the server does not have to track the Game's queue.  `Game.method`, running then in the Server's thread needs to put it in its private queue for its run method to pick up.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I will up-vote it, but Hemal, again, please see *why* I created the code I did. Again, it was not code for the OP to use in his program but just to illustrate a point. Please remove the down-vote.

Comment: Hotdamn, that makes total sense now! This has been most enlightening, I grant you the utmost gratitude for your time.

Comment: @Razor glad it helped, hopefully less confused about how java's (or any for that matter) threads work.

Answer (score 5):

@Razor, as per other discussion, if a class implements Runnable and the run method is tied up with a long running process, you can still call other methods of the class. And this can be tested like this:

```
public class TestThreads {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestGame testGame = new TestGame();
      new Thread(testGame).start();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         testGame.otherMethod();
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
      System.out.println("done");
      System.exit(0);
   }
}

class TestGame implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(100 * 1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }

   public void otherMethod() {
      System.out.println("in other method");
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, and then if done is never being printed in between the "in other methods" then chances are it is all running serially. Gotcha, thanks!

Comment: done is not printed until after the for loop because the for loop is running in series with done. Nothing fancy there.

Comment: -1. No! Don't do this. There is no point in writing a `Runnable` whose `run` method only `sleep`.

Comment: @HemalPandya: ease up. This is for illustrative purposes only. You obviously have not read question nor the discussion. You'd best not down vote before doing so lest you look foolish.

Comment: @HemalPandya: note that my code was not to show the original poster how to do things but that the methods of TestGame are called on the thread of the calling code, not the thread that the run method is called on. To see why I created this code, please see the comment list in Heisenburg's answer. I was only trying to illustrate that one point.

Comment: @Hemal: It illustrates that if the runnable is fully locked by a Thread.sleep() (which I agree is not a good thing to do in code in general), another class can still call the methods of the class that implements Runnable since those methods will run on the calling class's thread, that's it. That was the question that was discussed in Heisenberg's answer's comment thread.

Comment: @Hovercraft if I understand right you are trying to explain that otherMethod is executing in caller thread by ensuring that its own run is doing nothing. I was confused because it looks here like an answer. It would have been better as a comment to Heisenburg's answer.

Comment: @HemalPandya: I wish it could be a comment, but you cannot post code in a comment. It was showing that even if the runnable is totally locked, the class itself is not locked, that other methods can be called. The Thread.sleep(...) was just to illustrate say a long-running process. Surely you have used Thread.sleep in this way.  But I will update the text of my answer to reflect the discussion from heisenberg's answer.

Comment: I removed the down-vote. You can post code in comment between back-ticks but it may not look as pretty if there is a lot of it.

Comment: @HemalPandya: thank you. the code would look pretty darn ugly.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, is capturePiece() being run on the Game thread, or the
>   Server's thread?

capturePiece will run on the Game thread, where the method has been called.

> In this case, what would run() even do?

If it always the Server who calls method on Game threads, then you could do the same with a single thread.
Threads will be useful if the actions were triggered by each Game thread that independently call Server to notify the result.

Comment: Where the method's been called.

Comment: So if I put a wait() or sleep() in the run() method, will calling the other methods give an implicit interrupt or notify to the Game object?

Inside Server, game.capturePiece() is being called

Comment: I'm not understanding your last comment, could you clarify?

Comment: @RazorStorm: No. If you cause the game object's runnable to sleep, the other methods can still be called by the Server since the methods will be called on the thread from which they have been called on, here the Server's thread. Shoot, this should be simple enough to test in a small test program. Why not give it a try?

Comment: Ah, I suspected that it would run in the Caller's thread. Seeing as a method call is simply an underlying `jump` instruction (or whatever the javabyte code's equivalent to a jump). This will simply move the PC to the new location and nowhere in here is there an explicit context switch. 

How would you test this with a program? How do I see which thread is being run?